# How can I fit a function onto a histogram?

Tags: interpolation, histograms

```
SampleData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[3], 5000];
Histogram[SampleData]
```

This creates a histogram that (in my case) looks something like this:

[image]

I want to fit this histogram with a curve. The documentation of [RandomVariate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) shows something similar to what I had in mind:

[image]

(However the blue line isn't actually a fitted curve; the documentation is simply plotting the [known] analytical formula.)

How can I fit the histogram? The obvious way is to use `Interpolation`, but the naive attempt to `Interpolation[Histogram[SampleData]]` doesn't work; Mathematica complains that the histogram is not a list of data and coordinates.

**Edit**: My raw data contains about 6000 points and looks like this:

[image]

This isn't what I'm trying to fit however; I want to fit the histogram, which looks like this:

[image]

Ideally the defined "NewFunction" would be able to take input such as `NewFunction[3]` and return about 70. A normalized NewFunction would be even better.

Comment: how `SmoothKernelDistribution`, e.g., `Show[Histogram[SampleData, Automatic, PDF], 
 Plot[Evaluate@PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[SampleData]][x], {x, 0, 
   15}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]`?

Comment: @kglr that works, thanks!

Comment: Allure, posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: @kglr actually it doesn't work ... I found out when trying to apply `SmoothKernalDistribution` to my problem that it doesn't seem to involve a histogram, and therefore only works with this particular SampleData. I will edit the OP with more details.

Comment: Allure, you want to use bar width and height information from histogram to construct an estimated PDF?

Comment: @kglr Yes. Does the edit make it clearer what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Allure: You have the raw data.  Constructing a histogram and fitting it loses information.  You certainly don't want to use a regression function (`NonlinearModelFit`, for example).  With the large amount of data you have, using `SmoothKernelDistribution` as @kglr shows you is what you want.  If you have a particular probability distribution in mind, then you should consider `EstimatedDistribution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2:** Extracting bin center and height information from `Histogram` output  and using `Interpolation`:

```
histogram = Histogram[SampleSampleData];
datafromrectangles =  Cases[histogram, 
   Rectangle[a_, b_, ___] :> {Mean[{a[[1]], b[[1]]}], b[[2]]}, All];
intF = Interpolation[datafromrectangles];

Show[histogram, 
 Quiet@ Plot[intF[x], {x, 0, 15}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], Filling -> Axis]]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative using [`WeightedData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html) on histogram bin limits and heights combined with `Interpolation`:

```
{binlims, heights} = HistogramList[SampleData];
wd = WeightedData[MovingAverage[binlims, 2], heights];
bw = binlims[[2]] - binlims[[1]];
iF = (1/bw) Interpolation[Transpose[wd["EmpiricalPDF"]]][#] &;
Show[Histogram[SampleData, Automatic, PDF], 
 Quiet@ Plot[iF[x], {x, 0, 
       15}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], Filling -> Axis]]
```

[image]

**Note:** This approach works only for fixed bin width and `PDF` as the height function.

**Original answer:**

You can use [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) with `SampleData` as input to get a distribution object use its `PDF`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
SampleData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[3], 5000];
dist =SmoothKernelDistribution[SampleData];

Show[Histogram[SampleData, Automatic, PDF], 
  Plot[Evaluate@PDF[dist][x], {x, 0, 15}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick], Filling -> Axis]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second update worked for the sample data, but not the actual data; still I understand what you're doing and will adapt the code. Two questions: what does the "Empirical PDF" do? Also, for the third update, did you define a `histogram` somewhere previously? As it is, it doesn't run for me.

Comment: @Allure, forgot to copy/paste the line for `histogram`. For a `WeightedData` object `w`, the property `"EmpiricalPDF"` of `w` (accessed using `w["EmpiricalPDF"]`) gives two lists, the first containing _data values_ and the second _estimated weights_.

Answer (score 3):

How about just using `EstimatedDistribution`?

```
SampleData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[3], 5000];
fitDist = EstimatedDistribution[SampleData, RayleighDistribution[s]]
Show[
 Histogram[SampleData, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[fitDist, x], {x, 0, 12}]
]
```

> [image]

If you have an arbitrary PDF, you can fit to a `ProbabilityDistribution`:

```
fitDist = EstimatedDistribution[
 SampleData, 
 ProbabilityDistribution[(E^(-(x^2/(2 s^2))) x)/s^2, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}],
 {{s, 1}}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late in the game, If you want a more 'purist' approach, you could also use HistogramList to extract the points and then fit using an arbitrary function.

```
SampleData = RandomVariate[RayleighDistribution[3], 5000];
binSize = #[[1, 2]] - #[[1, 1]] &@HistogramList[SampleData];
SampleDataP = {#[[1, 2 ;;]] - 0.5 binSize, #[[2]]}\[Transpose] &@
   HistogramList[SampleData, Automatic, "PDF"];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[SampleDataP, 
   x/\[Sigma]^2 Exp[-x^2/(2 \[Sigma]^2)] , {\[Sigma]}, x];
fit["BestFitParameters"]
Show[{Histogram[SampleData, Automatic, "PDF"], ListPlot@SampleDataP, 
  Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 12}]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the model predicts quite well the parameter in question (don't forget to normalise the distribution! ;) )

Comment: You can do this, but a least-square fit of a histogram is generally a very bad method for distribution fitting and should be discouraged. The equal-variance assumption that `NonlinearModelFit` is not satisfied at all for histograms. A simple maximum likelihood fit would be far preferable.

Comment: I see. This is still new to me, just posted what I thought worked well. Does the EstimatedDistribution follow a maximum likelihood fit? Could one not request NonlinearModelFit to do the same?

Comment: `EstimatedDistribution` has a number of methods, but yes: maximum likelihood is one of them. I don't think you can poor this problem easily into `NonlinearModelFit` because it uses least-squares, but it's generally quite easy to implement your own maximum likelihood method with `NMaximize` or `FindMaximum`.

Comment: Hi again Sjoerd!
Would you be able to point me to some literature/concept as to why the equal variance method is generally bad for histograms? Does it have to do with how the bin placement is considered? Doing mini tests with various NonlinearModelFit methods produce virtually identical distributions. Is the issue with the complexity of the distribution or the bin size or something?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I know explicit literature that discusses this, but first and foremost: fitting histograms is simply not something that is done or recommended by any reasonable source on statistics. The main problem is that histograms are kinda arbitrary and depend on your choice of bin size. Max likelihood does not have that problem. The next problem is that histograms are always positive whereas NonlinearModelFit assumes an error model that does not enforce this positivity, so it's conceptually wrong as well. Of course, it can sometimes give reasonable results by accident.